# define function that takes 2 inputs in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to create a new column where the column takes 2 inputs: `last_purchase_in_days` and `order_count`.

Code:

```
def segmentor(last_purchase_in_days,order_count):
    if (customer_df['last_purchase_in_days'] <= 30) & (customer_df['order_count']>=4):
        return 'best',
    elif (customer_df['last_purchase_in_days'] <=180) & (customer_df['order_count']>=4):
        return 'loyal',
    elif (customer_df['last_purchase_in_days'] <=30) & (customer_df['order_count']==1):
        return 'recent',
    elif (customer_df['last_purchase_in_days'] <=180) & (customer_df['order_count']==1): 
        return 'defecting',
    elif (customer_df['last_purchase_in_days'] <=180) & (customer_df['order_count']<=3):
        return 'promising',
    elif (customer_df['last_purchase_in_days'] <=360):
        return 'at_risk',
    elif (customer_df['last_purchase_in_days'] >=360):
        return 'dormant',
    else: 
        return '???'

customer_df['segment']=customer_df.apply(lambda x: segmentor(x)
```

Error: `TypeError: segmentor() missing 1 required positional argument: 'order_count'.`

#*I don't put the last elif to else: return 'dormant' because I want to check if there anything that I missed.*

```
customer_df.dtypes
last_purchase_in_days    int64
order_count              int64
```

Comment: `x.segmentor` should probably be `segmentor(x)`

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: You are not using x in your function

Comment: revised the code, the problem is still not resolved.

Comment: You are missing a `)` in the end after `segmentor(x)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `apply` method runs per column, not per row, so you should add the `axis` argument. Then, your `segmentor` should operate on the row, not the entire dataframe.

```py
import pandas
import random

# Create some test data
my_df = pandas.DataFrame(
    [
        {
            "last_purchase_in_days": random.randint(0, 720),
            "order_count": random.randint(0, 6),
        }
        for _ in range(1000)
    ]
)


def segmentor(row):
    if (row["last_purchase_in_days"] <= 30) & (row["order_count"] >= 4):
        return "best"
    elif (row["last_purchase_in_days"] <= 180) & (row["order_count"] >= 4):
        return "loyal"
    elif (row["last_purchase_in_days"] <= 30) & (row["order_count"] == 1):
        return "recent"
    elif (row["last_purchase_in_days"] <= 180) & (row["order_count"] == 1):
        return "defecting"
    elif (row["last_purchase_in_days"] <= 180) & (row["order_count"] <= 3):
        return "promising"
    elif row["last_purchase_in_days"] <= 360:
        return "at_risk"
    elif row["last_purchase_in_days"] >= 360:
        return "dormant"

my_df["segment"] = my_df.apply(lambda x: segmentor(x), axis=1)
```